# Spacing between triple vertical lines

Tags: spacing, symbols, math-operators, delimiters

I would like to create a norm-like operator with 3 verticals bars instead of two. It has to look like `$|||\cdot|||$`. I would like to know how to decrease the spacing between the vertical bars such that it has the same spacing as the `$\lVert .. \rVert$` command.

There is a command available in the `stmaryrd` package called `\biginterleave`, but this command has to much spacing between the vertical bars, especially in display math mode.

Is there some work-around to adjust the spacing between to vertical bars?

Answer (score 30):

Here's a solution that doesn't require the use of additional packages. The new command, `\vertiii`, takes one argument; the triple vertical bars resize automatically depending on the size of the argument. For the MWE below, I've actually set the spacing between the vertical bars to be slightly *less* than what's generated by `\[l,r]Vert` -- you can adjust the spacing to suit your taste by changing the value of the argument of the four `\kern` commands.

**Addendum**: I've modified the code -- by inserting curly braces around the entire command -- to allow for the use of the command `\vertiii` in subscripts and superscripts as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\vertiii}[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}
\begin{document}
$\vertiii{a}$, 
$\vertiii{\int_0^1 a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}$,
$\displaystyle \vertiii{\int_0^1 a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}_\vertiii{b}$

$\lVert a \rVert$ (for comparison)

$c_\vertiii{d}$, $f^\vertiii{g}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added a better image; however some artifact are unavoidable, unless a *very* large resolution is used. What are you using for conversion from PDF to PNG?

Comment: Thanks, @egreg! I use Acrobat 9.5 to save the file in png format. Is there a better converter I should be considering?

Comment: I always use ImageMagick's `convert`, with parameters `-density 300 -quality 90` (as does the `standalone` class). You should at least activate antialiasing.

Comment: @egreg - thanks, I will adopt your method from now on.

Comment: @PeterGrill -- many thanks for uploading a much higher quality image file!

Comment: I tried this solution, but my bars are not scaled equally. The inner bars are smaller than the outer ones.

Comment: @JakobW. - I just reran the code above, which I posted more than ten years ago by now. The result still looks just the same as in the screenshot shown above. All I can surmise is that your document setup differs significantly from mine. Sadly, my mind-reading skills are utterly worthless. So, do please provide more details about you have actually done.

Comment: @Mico EDIT: I use the `commath` package, which seems to cause this behaviour.

Comment: @JakobW. - There is only meaningful recommendation possible : **Don’t use `commath`**. Its irredeemable problem is that it rests on a fundamental misunderstanding of TeX’s math mode. The fact that (as a consequence of this well-known issue) it hasn’t been updated in nearly 20 years should also give you pause.

Answer (score 18):

A solution modelled on Mico's, but that allows also for use in subscripts and superscripts. Using `\mkern-1.5mu` seems better; this should be adjusted if other base fonts are used, comparing to what `\|` produces.

The syntax is similar to the one used by `mathtools` for "fenced" symbols:

```
\opnorm{a}        % normal size
\opnorm[\big]{a}  % slightly larger
\opnorm[\Bigg]{a} % largest
\opnorm*{a}       % \left and \right
```

Here's the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\opnorm}{\@ifstar\@opnorms\@opnorm}
\newcommand{\@opnorms}[1]{%
  \left|\mkern-1.5mu\left|\mkern-1.5mu\left|
   #1
  \right|\mkern-1.5mu\right|\mkern-1.5mu\right|
}
\newcommand{\@opnorm}[2][]{%
  \mathopen{#1|\mkern-1.5mu#1|\mkern-1.5mu#1|}
  #2
  \mathclose{#1|\mkern-1.5mu#1|\mkern-1.5mu#1|}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\opnorm{a}$,
$\opnorm[\Big]{\int_0^1 a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}$,
$\displaystyle \opnorm*{\int_0^1 a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}_{\opnorm{a}}$

$\lVert a \rVert$ (for comparison)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The [fourier package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) provides such a symbol, called `\VERT`. However, `\usepackage{fourier}` will change the font throughout your document. You can access just this one symbol by adding its definition (taken from [fourier.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fourier-GUT/tex/latex/fourier/fourier.sty)) to your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMS}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontEncoding{FMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fouriersymbols}{FMS}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fourierlargesymbols}{FMX}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\VERT}{\mathord}{fouriersymbols}{152}{fourierlargesymbols}{147}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[ 
\VERT x \VERT \quad \left\VERT\frac{1}{2}\right\VERT 
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

A solution using `\vvvert` of package `mathabx`. The symbol can also be used with `\left` and `\right`. Since the package changes many math symbols, the following example only defines `\vvvert` and the symbol fonts, needed for it without changing other math symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathabx}

% Math symbol font matha
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Math symbol font mathb
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

% Symbol definition
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vvvert}{0}{matha}{"7E}{mathx}{"17}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left\vvvert \frac{A}{B}\right\vvvert
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]