# How to write norm symbol with three line?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to have a norm symbol with three line in my equation such as `|||x|||` but with equal distances.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems already discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54385/spacing-between-triple-vertical-lines Can you tell if it helps?

Comment: Don't worry for the closure: it happens to newcomers. I had to try a few keys for finding the appropriate question (and note that I actually had answered it): the site is big and it's not easy to find one's way in it. Welcome again!