# Norm with triple vertical lines using `DeclarePairedDelimiter`

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

I would like to declare a paired delimiter for a "triple norm".
A answer to this question already exists (cf. 
[Spacing between triple vertical lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54385)), however, as I'm already using `mathtools`' `DeclarePairedDelimiter*` macros a lot, I would like to stay consistent and use them.

I tried to declare "naively" my norm like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\normi}[1]
  {|||}
  {|||}
  {\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}}

\begin{document}    
\(\normiii{x}\)

\(\normiii{}\)    
\[
    \normiii*{\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k}
\]    
\end{document}
```

However, only the first bar is stretched. Is there a way to group the 3 bars such that they all stretch?

PS: I would prefer not to use a custom font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain it with `\vvvert` from `mathabx`. Here is a code to use it without loading the mathabx package:

*Note*: You also have the `\vVert` and `\rVvert` delimiters in `fdsymbol`. Another possibility, if you happen to use `fourier`, is that it provides a `\VERT` command for the same delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
<-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
<10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vvvert} {0}{matha}{"7E}{mathx}{"17}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\normiii}[1]
{\vvvert}
{\vvvert}
{\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[ \normiii[\Big]{x^k } \qquad \normiii{} \]

\[ \normiii*{\sum_{k \geq 0}^\infty a_k} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: There seem to be some formatting issues. BTW, I cannot really see the a difference to the other answer, which also uses `\vvvert` without `mathabx`.

Comment: I guess @Schrödinger'scat was posting while  I was trying various possibilities and I didn't check whether there already was an answer. However, I didn't copy the link! I think I'll update as soon as I've found the encoding of \Vvert in `fdsymbol`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [one of the very answers you link to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193126/194703).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Math symbol font matha
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Math symbol font mathb
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

% Symbol definition
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vvvert}{0}{matha}{"7E}{mathx}{"17}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\normi}[1]
  {\vvvert}
  {\vvvert}
  {\ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\(\normi{x}\)

\(\normi{}\)
\[
  \normi*{\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]