# Matrix Norms notation

Tags: macros, matrices, vector

Im writing a paper on norms, we use two bars `\|\cdot\|` for vector norms and triple bars for matrix norms. The problem is that if I use `|||\cdot|||` the distances between the bars is different and that bothers me (using `\||` is just horrible). I wanted to make a new command but i cant make the distance between the bars small enough to look like the vector norm. This is what I tried:

```latex
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{|\hspace{0.05mm}|\hspace{0.05mm}|\hspace{0.05mm}#1\hspace{0.05mm}|\hspace{0.05mm}|\hspace{0.05mm}}
```

I don't know how to make the distance smaller, maybe there's another command for smaller distances that I'm not familiarized with.

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Did you see the posting [Spacing between triple vertical lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54385/5001)?

Comment: I didn't, it was helpful, thanks!!

Comment: There's also a possibility with `mathabx`. You may take a look at  the answers to [this  question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510321/norm-with-triple-vertical-lines-using-declairepaireddelimiter)